# IOError: No suitable library found for xls

Tags: python-2.7, ioerror, pyexcel

Working on a project that uses pyexcel to read and write .xls files which is compiled using py2exe.

I get this error after compiling and confirming that pyexcel, pyexcel-io and pyexcel-xls are in the library.zip folder.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "FundDatabase.pyo", line 391, in get_worksheet

File "pyexcel\core.pyo", line 118, in get_book

File "pyexcel\core.pyo", line 137, in _get_book

File "pyexcel\sources\file_source_input.pyo", line 52, in get_data

File "pyexcel_io\io.pyo", line 31, in get_data

File "pyexcel_io\io.pyo", line 118, in load_data_new

File "pyexcel_io\manager.pyo", line 94, in create_reader

File "pyexcel_io\manager.pyo", line 89, in _get_a_handler

IOError: No suitable library found for xls
```

[here is my project library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtiqR.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**

You will need to tell pyinstaller about the hidden imports about pyexcel-xls.

In order to package pyexcel-xls, you need to specify:

```
--hidden-import pyexcel_xls
--hidden-import pyexcel_xls.xlsr
--hidden-import pyexcel_xls.xlsw
```

Reference: [mechanism of dynamic load module, confilict with pyinstaller/cx_freeze's execution](https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel-xlsx/issues/19)

**Long Answer**

Since version 0.5.0, pyexcel uses [lazy loading](http://lml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/design.html), which creates a problem for pystaller because not all modules are loaded on program's startup. Hence, you will need to tell pyinstaller about the missing imports(a.k.a hidden imports).

**Pyinstaller notes**

http://pyexcel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyinstaller.html

http://pyexcel-io.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyinstaller.html